# Problem launching docker-compose : python modules not installed

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

I'm getting python error, trying to do a "docker-compose up" in the app folder.

I get theses errors :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.28.0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 131, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 212, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Here is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

The docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: sqlite
    environment:
      - SQLITE_DB=sqlite
      - SQLITE_USER=sqlite
      - SQLITE_PASSWORD=sqlite
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The requirements.txt :

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.8
```

I'm new using docker. I try to dockerize an existing Django app. I'm not sure is the problem is due to docker-compose itself, or the command launched to install requirements.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you update your question with docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: That error looks like it's in Compose on your host, which happens to also be a Python application, and suggests Docker isn't running.  Do minimal things like `docker info` work?  Have you set the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to anything?  What is your host operating system?

Answer (score 52):

I got a similar errorcode, but my solution was quite simple: docker wasn't running.

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: Docker was simply not running, so I turned it on...

Comment: At MacOS start Docker App.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be due to a user rights problem.

If I launcher docker-compose up as normal user, I get this error.

Wereas, if I lauch it sudo... it seems to work, but fails with an error on sqlite :

```
Pulling db (sqlite3:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling db (sqlite3:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for sqlite3, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Seems django doesn't like sqlite in Docker...

I'm on ArchLinux.

Here is the docker info

:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.13-ce
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: c623d1b36f09f8ef6536a057bd658b3aa8632828.m
 runc version: ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.9.2-arch1-1
 Operating System: Arch Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.48GiB
 Name: OCTO-JBAL
 ID: AI6G:SVGS:4YDY:U37Q:BE7E:MW6P:CY4E:BLPY:AN3D:QODN:4ZIJ:4OHX
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

It seems $DOCKER_HOST is empty... but cannot know which value to set on this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar errors when launching docker-compose. In my case, I had not installed docker prior to installing docker-compose. This was on fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.